# How do we use Integer or Long type of objects as Foreign key mapping in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, entity-relationship

I tried below sample code which does not seem to work, while trying to fetch the object from table, hibernate tries to set the User Object on top of Long objects and fails when tried to load the Parent entity which has this createdBy field

any help?

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
private Long createdBy;
```

I want to use Long/Integer as type of the field and want to make sure its a valid Foreign key to User table which has Primary key USER_ID

Please note that i DO NOT want to use User as type of my object, for example , i do not want below declaration in my class

private User createdBy;

Edit:
Reason for such requirement:

Ahh well!!, i'll try to keep it short which is basically one of the problem with ORM's like Hibernate. I have a Super Class AuditLogModel which is extended by each and every entity class in my software (100+ entities). This AuditLogModel class has CreatedBy & ModifiedBy field. If i keep the types of this fields as User, then every entity in my software tries to create a join with user table twice on operations like getResultsList/Merge/refresh, where Merge and Refresh calls on entity manger cannot be controlled by us, its all eager loading in one select query. Since my entities have child entities and they have further childs and so on, this creates more than 61 joins and sometime 100+ joins and causes query performance issues. These createdBy and modified by columns are updated with every insert/update but not required with any query when any entity is loaded, and hence I want to avoid the unneccessari joins here. Hope its understood

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to use `User`? Which will do exactly what you want (have an relationship with another table). If you want to make sure it is a valid foreign key, just add a constraint to the table (and no letting Hibernate manage your schema isn't a proper way of adding it, use something like Flyway or Liquibase to manage your schema).

Answer (score 0):

Ah OneToOne mapping is used for Entities like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@OneToOne
private User createdBy;
```

If you want to use just the database value then you must remove the OneToOne mapping:

```
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long createdBy;
```

Comment: I want to use Long and not User as type of my createdBy field

Comment: Checkout my updated answer

Comment: ill repeat, I want to use Long and not User as type of my createdBy field – i.e. private Long createdBy; hope you got what i mean. Also by just mentioning the column without mapping, it wont enforce foreign key constraint to User table (User Id) which is indeed needed. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the type of the variable. Have a look

Comment: You talking basics here which I am very well aware of. This wont create foreign key, which is needed

Comment: Finally I understand your question! You want to create the database from the mapping! Without the OneToOne to the User there will be no foreign key.